# Let $\vec v_{1}, \vec v_{2}, \vec v_{3}$ be eigenvalues of the matrix A. Express $\vec x$ as a linear combination of the vectors and find $A \vec x$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have vectors: $\vec v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$ , $\vec v_{2} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $\vec v_{3} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$ and they are eigenvectors of the matrix $A$ which corresponds to the eigenvalues: $\lambda_{1} = -2$, $\lambda_{2} = -1$, $\lambda_{3} = 2$, and let $\vec x =$ $\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 0 \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}$.

Express $\vec x$ as a linear combination of $\vec v_{1}, \vec v_{2}, \vec v_{3}$ and find $A\vec x$.

So I solved the linear combination part by performing $rref(A)$ and finding that the linear combination of the $\vec x$ is:

$\vec x = -2\vec v_{1} - 2\vec v_{2} -1 \vec v_{3}$.

Now I don't know how to solve the last bit of the problem, find $A \vec x$.

My thinking was $A$ is the eigenvalue and I could do the following:

$\lambda_{1} \vec v_{1} + \lambda_{2} \vec v_{2} + \lambda_{3} \vec v_{3} = A\vec x$. (I am incorrect.)

Any thoughts on how I could solve the last part? I thought A being an eigenvalue I could find $A\vec x$ the way I showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$Ax = A(-2v_1 - 2v_2 - 1v_3) = -2Av_1 -2Av_2 -1 Av_3 = -2 \lambda_1v_1 -2 \lambda_2 v_2 - \lambda_3 v_3 = 4v_1 + 2v_2 -2 v_3$

Then plug in $v_1, v_2, v_3$

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by diagonalization of $A$. Since $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and there are $3$ linearly independent eigenvector, then $A$ can be diagonalized as follows:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
\vec{v}_1 &| \vec{v}_2 &| \vec{v}_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\vec{v}_1 &| \vec{v}_2 &| \vec{v}_3
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \\
= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & 2 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & 2 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \\
= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & 2 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} \frac{1}{10} \begin{pmatrix}
4 & -2 & 2 \\
4 & 3 & 2 \\
6 & -3 & -2
\end{pmatrix} \\
= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 2 \\
4 & -2 & 0 \\
-6 & 0 & -4 \end{pmatrix} \frac{1}{10} \begin{pmatrix}
4 & -2 & 2 \\
4 & 3 & 2 \\
6 & -3 & -2
\end{pmatrix} \\
= \frac{1}{10} \begin{pmatrix}
8 & - 9 & -6 \\
8 & -14 & 4 \\
-48 & 24 & -4 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that this only works when $A$ has the same number of eigenvectors as its square matrix dimension.

Comment: Diagonalization is overkill for this problem.

Comment: Yes, but this is a volatile problem. Sure it is not the most beautiful way to do it, but might be helpful for someone else dealing with a deficient matrix. In which case they can easily generalize this with Jordan canonical form.

Comment: With a deficient matrix, they won't have enough data to ask the question OP posed. They'd have to have generalized eigenvectors, in which case the approach taken in the answer by Coriolanus is still much simpler than the approach via canonical forms.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. Didn’t realize Coronalius’ approach would be applicable to generalized eigenvectors as well.